# r barplot 2 series display labels on x axis

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I have code as below. I want to put labels on x axis, but I am getting a below error.

How could I plot labels without repeating them on the x axis?

How could I add the legend?

```
animal=c("a","b")
height=c(5,6)
weight=c(7,9)
bb=barplot(rbind(height,weight), col=c("darkblue","red"),beside = TRUE)
grid(lty=8,col="black")
axis(1,at=bb,labels=animal,las=2)
```

Comment: This is discussed in `?barplot` - "*If beside is true, use colMeans(mp) for the midpoints of each group of bars, see example.*" - so `axis(1,at=colMeans(bb),labels=animal,las=2)`

Comment: thanks...How could I add the legend? I am trying to go through documentation, but not finding anyting

Comment: Did you do a search for "legend" in `?barplot` - it's mentioned a bunch of times, including reproducible examples at the end of the documentation page.

Comment: i just found it `legend = c("height","weight")` does the trick. But now i need to figure out how to move this legend to `topleft` corner

Comment: i saw that in general i could do `legend("topleft")`, but in this current case I am not sure as I am using `legend = c("height","weight")`. Would appreciate your help

Comment: Again, an example with 'topleft' is literally at the bottom of the `?barplot` doc page. `legend.text = c("A", "B"), args.legend = list(x = "topleft")`

Comment: Sorry, this i embarrassing. I was trying to search on the page `https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/legend.html`